# Протокол JSONP. Обработка ответа, JSONP. Обнаружение ошибок

Tags: json, jsonp

Как создать запрос JSONP,и как обработать ответ JSONP.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с этим ?

И вообще есть ли разница между JSON и JSONP ?

Спасибо

Comment: Зачем вы изменяете вопрос годовалой давности на другой и снимаете галочку с моего ответа?

Comment: @Firepro Поступило сообщение что мой вопрос порождает трения.и что стоит переформулировать.После этого немного странно выглядел ваш ответ.И я поступил согласно правилам stackoverflow

Comment: о чем вы? какие трения? Посмотрите историю, ваш вопрос звучал корректно "Как создать запрос JSONP, и как обработать ответ JSONP И есть ли разница между JSON и JSONP?" - здесь вопрос корректный и ответ на него может быть основан только на знаниях, а не на мнениях, и не может порождать бесконечных дискуссий, так как имеет практический однозначное направление ответа.

Comment: Радикальное изменение вопроса, на который уже дан хороший ответ - плохая идея.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разница безусловно есть. JSON это простой формат данных, а JSONP представляет собой методологию для использования этого формата с кросс-доменными AJAX запросами.

**Обычный JSON**:

```
{"why":"not"}
```

**JSONP**:

```
bestFunction({"why":"not"});
```

Получается, что JSONP вы можете использовать в качестве сценария. Будет вызвана функция bestFunction, которую вы написали ранее, и при запуске ей будет передан JSON в качестве параметра. Данный метод используется для обеспечения кросс-доменных AJAX запросов.

Обработка может выглядеть вот так:

```
function bestFunction(json){
  console.log(json.why);
}

var elm = document.createElement("script");
elm.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
elm.src = "http://test.ru/jsonp";
document.body.appendChild(elm);
```

По сути, Вы добавляете тег сценария на вашу страницу, который загружает данные в виде сценария JavaScript и делает обратный вызов вашего кода с данными. Следовательно вы можете запрашивать данные с любого сервера, в любом браузере, без каких-либо разрешений и дополнительных проверок, которые присутствуют в AJAX запросах.